# Multi-segmented bezier path with equidistant steps

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, points, bezier

I'd like to step over a multi-segmented bezier path with equidistant steps. For example, I want to step over the bezier curve in 20 steps. Then what I need as result is an array containing the coordinates of the 20 points. Can I use CAKeyframeAnimation to calculate these positions on a bezier? I know you can create an animation from a bezier path. e.g.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *positionAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
positionAnimation.path = bezierpath.CGPath;
```

But can you access information about positions of such a created animation? Can these positions be extracted and how?

Comment: can you add some tags to explain which language/framework you're using?

Comment: Done. It's for iOS and I'm using the SpriteKit framework.

Comment: it may also be worth rephrasing your question a little after reading the [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) article, because it looks like you jumped the gun on what the solution should be, and you're asking about your imagined solution rather than how to solve the original problem (also known as the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378))